# Sort equal ranges within std::multiset

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, multiset

Suppose I have a multiset of `T` with key comparison function `Comp1`. Suppose that `Comp2` is a finer key comparison function, so `a<b` under `Comp1` implies `a<b` under `Comp2`, but not always vice versa (so `Comp2` is able to further sort equal-ranges of `Comp1`). How would I sort `T` using `Comp2`? (I know that with C++11, multiset will keep a stable sorting order.)

Comment: Do you mean, "How do I sort `multiset<Key, Value, Comp1>` with `Comp2`?"

Comment: Why cant you just use comp2 as the comparator?

Comment: Are you trying to use `Comp2` to sort values of the same key?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't specify more than one sort order for a multimap.

The order of any elements that compare equally for the multimap compare function are not configurable.

The closest you might get is:

> 1. Create a CBucket based on a std::map that sorts its elements by the comp2 comparator.
> 2. Create a std::map<key, CBucket, comp1>
>
> retrieve the correct bucket from then select the right data.

However, before going down a path like that you might want to ask why you need this kind of access and why you aren't just using comp2 as the multimap's compare function.  If you explain a bit more about the problem you are solving, there might be a more appropriate data structure that you could choose.